# What does the '$' operator do in this R code snippet?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following R dplyr code:

```
lahmanNames %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "dataframe") %>%   # Bind the data frames
  filter(var == "playerID") %>%   # Filter the results
  `$`(dataframe)   #  <---- WHAT DOES $ MEAN?
```

What does the $ operator refer to in this case?

Comment: It means you are `pull`ing out the 'dataframe' column. Instead of that notation, use `%>% pull(dataframe)` to get that column

Comment: All answers and the comment were useful, thank you. Unfortunately I can only select one right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just like doing `mtcars$dataframe`. there are a bunch of ways to do this. In `dplyr` 0.7.0 the function [`pull`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pull.html) was added, which does this in a way that works with piping (`%>%`).

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% `$`(mpg)

#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2
#> [15] 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4
#> [29] 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

mtcars$mpg

#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2
#> [15] 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4
#> [29] 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

mtcars[["mpg"]]

#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2
#> [15] 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4
#> [29] 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4

mtcars %>% pull(mpg)

#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2
#> [15] 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4
#> [29] 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`$`(x, y)
```

is a different way to write

```
x[[y, exact = FALSE]]
```

That is to say, if `y = "foo"`, then

```
`$`(x, y)
```

is identical to

```
x$foo
```